# HTTP Status >= 300 Returning JSON

Tags: rest, http, backend

I was wondering if it is acceptable/common to have a server return a JSON response along side a 3xx or 4xx response?

The reason I ask this is because I do return a JSON response with more details regarding the error, but [it seems the engine I am using doesn't agree with what I am doing](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/network/HttpAsynConnection.m#L90). I would like to make sure my approach is acceptable before submitting a PR.

Comment: If you are responding with error information then take a look at https://github.com/blongden/vnd.error, https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-http-problem-00 and http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/05/error-handling-considerations-and-best.html for some ideas about what to include and how to represent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine for 3xx or 4xx responses to have body entities, sometimes it's even required.

For example, for [`300 Multiple Choices`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3):

> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate.